# IONOS Python Server Instantly Breaks With Any Changes

Tags: python, flask, ionos

I have a 1&1 Ionos server running Python. For some reason, the entire thing breaks when I try to make changes, even extremely simple changes. For example, I had this code in my main Python file:
(I am running Python Flask)

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "hi"
```

This worked 100%. However, when I changed it to this:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
  a = "hi"
  return a
```

This breaks.

Why? Does IONOS's python server not have the ability to handle variables and other simple things, or is their some way around this?

**Edit:** By break, I mean it goes to the sedo parking page instead of my page.

Comment: What does "break" mean exactly? Without any error messages it won't be possible to give helpful advise.

Comment: @KlausD. Instead of displaying my page, it goes to the SEDO parking page.

Comment: Then there is most likely a problem somewhere else like with the DNS setup of the domain. We can't assist with that.

Comment: @KlausD. Is there anything I can do to fix this?